# disconnecting from a socket in java

Tags: java, sockets

Hi 
i am building a little p2p program, implementing both the server-side and the client-side. 
when I lunch the client-side program, first think it does is to connect to each server in its list, send data (about the client-side) and disconnect. The next time the client-side connects to one of these servers it will be recognized.

My problem - when i tell the client-side to disconnect, i get this exception

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at oop.ex3.nameserver.NameServerThread.run(NameServerThread.java:24)
```

to disconnect i just wrote:

```
 finally {
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    }
```

so, how do i avoid this exception? thanks!

Comment: Uhh, have you thought about what would happen if any of the individual `close()` statements throw an exception?

Answer (score 11):

The JavaDoc for Socket.close() states clearly:

> Closing this socket will also close
>   the socket's InputStream and
>   OutputStream.

which will throw the exception since you've already closed them!

Answer (score 0):

When you close the client side, what would you expect to happen on the server side?

To avoid this exception, you need to implement you own readUnsignedShort() method like.

```
public int readUnsignedShort() {
   int ch1 = in.read();
   int ch2 = in.read();
   if ((ch1 | ch2) < 0)
//     don't throw new EOFException(); 
       return -1; // EOF marker.

   return (ch1 << 8) + (ch2 << 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be right doing a flush before closing the output streams?:

```
finally {
    //this is the DataOutputStream
    if(dout != null){
        dout.flush();
        dout.close();
    }
    //and this the OutputStream
    if(out != null){
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    if (din != null){
        din.close();
    }
    if (in != null){
        in.close();
    }
    if (socket != null){
        socket.close();
    }
}
```